# Modify Python virtualenv to not reference global Python installation

Tags: python, virtualenv

How do you modify a Python virtual environment so that it doesn't reference the global Python site-packages?

I created a virtualenv, and installed dozens of packages, some that are C-extensions and took a while to build, but I accidentally forgot to include the `--no-site-packages` flag, causing it to be linked it to the global site-packages. I don't want to just delete it and re-install all over again. Is there an easy way to de-link it from the global site-packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [virtualenvwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) and :

```
env1)$ toggleglobalsitepackages
  Disabled global site-packages
```

OR :
Create an empty file called no-global-site-packages.txt and put it into the virtualenv's folder lib/python2.7/

Comment: That package does not seem to include any command called `toggleglobalsitepackages`. However, adding the file worked.